# shuffle slider display

Tags: php, javascript, slider

i have a problem on the slider of my site, though the slider works fine and good but i need it to be random or shuffle instead of displaying an ordered content..
i already have the code and it need some modification.

this is the line on the main file.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider1').s3Slider({

        timeOut: 8000

    });
});
```

```
<div id="slider1">
    <ul id="slider1Content">
        <li class="slider1Image">
            <a href="goo.com"><img src="products/1.png" alt="1" /></a>
            <span class="left">
            caption1 
            </span>
        </li>

        <li class="slider1Image">
            <a href=""><img src="products/2.png" alt="2" /></a>
            <span class="right">caption2
            </span>
        </li>

        <li class="slider1Image">
            <a href=""><img src="products/3.png" alt="3" /></a>
            <span class="right">caption3. 
            </span>
        </li></div>
```

this is the java script file

```
(function($){  

$.fn.s3Slider = function(vars) {       



    var element     = this;
    var timeOut     = (vars.timeOut != undefined) ? vars.timeOut : 4000;
    var current     = null;
    var timeOutFn   = null;
    var faderStat   = true;
    var mOver       = false;
    var items       = $("#" + element[0].id + "Content ." + element[0].id + "Image");
    var itemsSpan   = $("#" + element[0].id + "Content ." + element[0].id + "Image span");

    items.each(function(i) {

        $(items[i]).mouseover(function() {
           mOver = true;
        });

        $(items[i]).mouseout(function() {
            mOver   = false;
            fadeElement(true);

        });

    });

    var fadeElement = function(isMouseOut) {
        var thisTimeOut = (isMouseOut) ? (timeOut/2) : timeOut;
        thisTimeOut = (faderStat) ? 10 : thisTimeOut;
        if(items.length > 0) {
            timeOutFn = setTimeout(makeSlider, thisTimeOut);
        } else {
            console.log("Poof..");
        }
    }

    var makeSlider = function() {

        current = (current != null) ? current : items[(items.length-1)];
        var currNo      = jQuery.inArray(current, items) + 1
        currNo = (currNo == items.length) ? 0 : (currNo - 1);
        var newMargin   = $(element).width() * currNo;
        if(faderStat == true)

        {
            if(!mOver) {
                $(items[currNo]).fadeIn((timeOut/6), function() {
                    if($(itemsSpan[currNo]).css('bottom') == 0) {
                        $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideUp((timeOut/6), function() {
                            faderStat = false;
                            current = items[currNo];
                            if(!mOver) {
                                fadeElement(false);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideDown((timeOut/6), function() {
                            faderStat = false;
                            current = items[currNo];
                            if(!mOver) {
                                fadeElement(false);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            if(!mOver) {
                if($(itemsSpan[currNo]).css('bottom') == 0) {
                    $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideDown((timeOut/6), function() {
                        $(items[currNo]).fadeOut((timeOut/6), function() {
                            faderStat = true;
                            current = items[(currNo+1)];
                            if(!mOver) {
                                fadeElement(false);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideUp((timeOut/6), function() {
                    $(items[currNo]).fadeOut((timeOut/6), function() {
                            faderStat = true;
                            current = items[(currNo+1)];
                            if(!mOver) {
                                fadeElement(false);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    makeSlider();

};})(jQuery);
```

i am struggling modifying this script for almost a week ... please help

Comment: I don't think you can without serious rewrite, it is iterating through elements (by order).

Comment: .. oh so it required to remake it from the scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your still looking for a solution... I've just done this, but thought it would have been a better method to write the li tags out server side by calling them from a random array. That's if your using server side scriptiing - Below is what I did in php.

> $arr = array("
>   Some text",  "
>   Some text", "
>   Some text", );

```
        $arrCnt = count($arr);
```

> ```
>         for ($i=0; $i<=$arrCnt; $i++)
>         {
>
>             $random = array_rand($arr);
>
>           echo "<li class='sliderImage'>";
>             echo $arr[$random];
>           echo "</li>\n";   
>
>           if($i<$arrCnt-1)
>               unset($arr[$random]);
>         }
>     ?>
> ```

Hope that helps.